# service kube-system/heapster has no node port, Grafana no health point

Tags: docker, kubernetes, grafana, minikube, heapster

i'm working on minikube and i have add this addons " heapster ".

When i open grafana on navigator, there is no health point, no cluster, no pods ... nothing.

i have this following error:

```
minikube addons open heapster
```

````
|  NAMESPACE  |   NAME   | TARGET PORT |     URL      |```
|-------------|----------|-------------|--------------|
| kube-system | heapster |             | No node port |
|-------------|----------|-------------|--------------|
  service kube-system/heapster has no node port
|-------------|--------------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
|  NAMESPACE  |        NAME        | TARGET PORT |             URL             |
|-------------|--------------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
| kube-system | monitoring-grafana |             | http://192.168.99.100:30002 |
|-------------|--------------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
  Opening kubernetes service  kube-system/monitoring-grafana in default browse```
````

Another information:

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/coredns-5644d7b6d9-9ddqz           1/1     Running   0          133m
pod/coredns-5644d7b6d9-rw8gb           1/1     Running   0          133m
pod/etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          132m
pod/heapster-kq4pk                     1/1     Running   0          43m
pod/influxdb-grafana-wdjjf             2/2     Running   0          43m
pod/kube-addon-manager-minikube        1/1     Running   0          132m
pod/kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          132m
pod/kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          132m
pod/kube-proxy-7h8cv                   1/1     Running   0          133m
pod/kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          132m
pod/storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   0          133m

NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
service/heapster              ClusterIP   10.110.62.76    <none>        80/TCP                   43m
service/kube-dns              ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   133m
service/monitoring-grafana    NodePort    10.108.34.225   <none>        80:30002/TCP             43m
service/monitoring-influxdb   ClusterIP   10.96.148.115   <none>        8083/TCP
```

Can you hep me please

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation? If so which one? 
The only thing I could find was this: 
https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster/blob/master/docs/influxdb.md
This project is not being maintained anymore, not a good sign.
Please provide your deployment YAML file (if possible).

Comment: @Julie please provide deployment files and minikube version.